# In how many ways we can move from $(0,0)$ to $(10,10)$ without crossing the line where y=x.

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

Suppose you are in $(0,0)$ you have to go to $(10,10)$ without crossing the line where y = x.
You can only move upwards or rightwards.

I have noticed that it is only asking the $10th$ Catalan number. But how I can prove it?

Comment: Construct a bijection between your case and Dyck paths (the definition of Catanal numbers). Hint: you can see it :)

Comment: Are you allowed to choose whether to go above or below the line $x = y$? Are you allowed to take a path that lands you _on_ the line but does not cross it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identify each path with an ordered sequence of
$10$ $H's$ (horizontal movements) and $10$ $V's$
(vertical movements). Thus, the number of paths joining  $(0,0)$ to $(10,10)$ (being allowed to touch the line $y=x+1$)
is $\displaystyle P_{20}^{10,10}=\binom{20}{10}.$

To get the number of paths that doesn't touch the line $y=x+1$ we will get the number of paths touching it. Let $c$ be a path joining $(0,0)$ and
$(10,10)$  that touches the line $y=x+1.$ Then, there exists an integer 
$i$ such that in the first $i$ steps of $c$ it holds that
$\mbox{number of}\: V= \mbox{number of}\: H+1.$
Suppose that $i$ is the smallest integer satisfying this property. So we can write $i=2j+1,$ where $j=\mbox{number of}\: H.$ To $c$ we will associate the path $c'$ defined by:

- $c'$ and $c$ share the first $2j+1$ steps,
- The following $2(10-j)-1$ steps of $c'$ are obtained from those in $c$
  changin each $H$ in $c$ by one $V$ and each $V$ by one $H.$

Since the last $2(10-j)-1$ steps of $c$
have $10-j$ $H's$ and $9-j$  $V's,$ the step $c'$
contains $9$ $H's$ and $11$ $V's.$ That is, $c'$ is a paht joining $(0,0)$ y $(9,11).$ It is obvious that to each path $c$ correspond only one $c'.$

Conversely, each path $c'$ joining $(0,0)$ with $(9,11)$ must touch the line $y=x+1.$ In a similar way, we associate to $c'$ only one path, that joins
$(0,0)$ with $(10,10)$ and touches $y=x+1.$

So, the number of paths joining $(0,0)$ and $(10,10)$ without touching the line $y=x+1$ is $$\displaystyle \binom{20}{10}-
\binom{20}{9}=\frac{1}{11}\binom{20}{10}.$$